# Openfeint multiplayer game tutorial for android

Tags: android, multiplayer, openfeint

I'm interesting to develop an android turn-based online game. I read that is possible with OpenFeint, but I didn't found any library. Does anyone know any tutorial for this? Any other alternative?

I'm not interesting in WiFi or Bluetooth solutions, because that is "easy" to solve with sockets...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I have also users the [Skiller](http://www.skiller-games.com) Platform and found it very useful.
I have combined it with [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org/) (for its physics engine) and got a really cool multiplayer gaming experience.

Comment: thank you, I will try it. It seems interesting. Actually I'm using XAMP

Comment: @MrWhiteYoo : Can we customize the skiller ? I mean skiller have some ready made layout available for score listing,opened game etc. I like d that but I wont custom layouts. Can I use skiller ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to OpenFeint developers site, It should contain everything you need.
http://support.openfeint.com/dev/welcome/

Comment: Actually OpenFeint developers site is not that good of a resource to start using it. Things are lost all over the place, and most are quite unclear. I would really like to hear an answer from somewhere who has experience with OpenFeint, AFAIR there is no multiplayer support for Android just yet.

Comment: Bad news so. I'm trying to communicate two mobiles, like whatsapp to make a turn based multiplayer game, but I don't find anything...

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in this same subject for my brand new game and I felt on [Skiller](http://www.skiller-games.com/).
Even if it was difficult to find out info about this service from other users, it seems to have all I need for my turn-based game, so I suppose to use their SDK and test it on the field.
Besides, I have already used Scoreloop and it seems not have a real-time turn-based multiplayer feature and I think OpenFeint neither.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the openfeint multiplayer API.

It was (maybe still is) removed from the site for maintainence, but someone has posted a link to it in on of these posts:

https://ofdev.zendesk.com/entries/20256407-where-is-the-multiplayer-api